# Mongoose DBrefs - Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Team Schema holding details about teams, and a Match Schema to store these teams in. I am trying to make it so that the home/away teams in the Match Schema are references to the Team object. I have put my code below, I'm getting an error when saving the Team but I can't help but feel I have done something wrong with the Schema's or the saving of the Match. Can anyone help?

So far I have the following code:

Team.js extract

```
var Team = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'name' : { type : String,
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'Team name is required'],
              index : { unique : true }
            }
});

module.exports.Schema = Team;
module.exports.Model = mongoose.model('Team', Team);
```

Match.js extract

```
var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Team = require('../schemas/Team').Schema;

var Match = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'hometeam' : {
    type : Schema.ObjectId,
    ref : 'Team'
  },
  'awayteam' : {
    type : Schema.ObjectId,
    ref : 'Team'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Match', Match);
```

index.js

```
  app.get('/match', function(req, res) {
    var key = 1356136550152; // Reading
    Team.findByKey(key, function(err, team) {
      if(err) {
        res.send("An error occured");
      }
      if(!team) { 
        res.send("The team does not exist");
      }
      var match = new Match();
      match.hometeam = team;
      match.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
          util.log('Error while saving Match: ' + util.inspect(err));
          res.send("An error occured whilst saving the match");
        } else {
          res.send("Saved the match");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

ERROR:

```
Error while saving Match: { message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ name: \'testTeam\',\n  _id: 50d500663ca6067226000001,\n  __v: 0,\n  key: 1356136550152 }" at path "hometeam"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: 
   [ { name: 'testTeam',
       _id: 50d500663ca6067226000001,
       __v: 0,
       key: 1356136550152 } ],
  path: 'hometeam' }
```

Error with team._id

```
Error while saving Match: { [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: testdb.matches.$team.name_1  dup key: { : null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: testdb.matches.$team.name_1  dup key: { : null }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 8,
  ok: 1 }

db.matches.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "testdb.matches",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "key" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
        "ns" : "testdb.matches",
        "name" : "key_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "team.key" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
        "ns" : "testdb.matches",
        "name" : "team.key_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In `index.js` it should be:

```
match.hometeam = team._id;
```

instead of:

```
match.hometeam = team;
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding the new error message, it looks like you have a unique index on the `matches` collection that refers to fields that don't exist.  Drop it in the shell using:

```
db.matches.dropIndex('team.name_1')
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried this and have put the new error above in my original post.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong somewhere else in the code but I cannot see it

Comment: @germainelol Looks like you have a stray index on `matches` that's causing this.  See updated answer.

Comment: `{ "nIndexesWas" : 6, "ok" : 1 }` Has this worked do you think? Because I still get the same error

Comment: @germainelol Yes, that means it was successfully dropped.  You can see the indexes still present via `db.matches.getIndexes()`.

Comment: What should I be looking for here to delete any unwanted indexes? I have put the code from this in my original post, and when I print out the match I have saved, there are unwanted fields being printed which arent in my Schema.

Comment: @germainelol You need to drop the `"team.key_1"` index as well.  `db.matches.dropIndex('team.key_1')`.